# How do I remove the hyperlink from the products thumbnail in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the top 4 best selling products within a div on the home page of my wordpress site. I don't want them the be clickable, I just want them to be displayed. I've managed to remove the 'Add to Cart' button by implementing

```
#trending .add_to_cart_button, #trending span.price {
    display: none;
}
```

But the thumbnails and their title headings still remain as hyperlinks. I've searched around & tried a few things, none of which seem to have worked.
Can anyone help with this? All suggestions are very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
<div id="popular">
    <p class="trending-title">Popular Products</p>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[best_selling_products per_page="4"]'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution...

```
#popular .woocommerce ul.products li.product {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Does the trick.

Comment: be aware of compatibility. does it work in older browsers specially IE? I believe Javascript/Jquery would work as well

Comment: @VictorFerreira do you have another suggestion then?